# Documentation for the TWINKLE SPARQL query engine

Tags: sparql

I have a problem with a SPARQL query engine called "TWINKLE" . Although i found the executible file and it was working perfectly , I failed to find any manual on the net about the usage of TWINKLE. As I am new to the SPARQL querying , i need a bit of help on that regard. CAn anyone suggest how to get more info or help regarding this??

Thanks.
Rajroshan Sawhney.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about Leigh Dodd's [Twinkle](http://www.ldodds.com/projects/twinkle/) tool? I agree that the documention isn't that obvious.

Leigh's [talk to Oxford SWIG](http://www.ldodds.com/blog/2008/03/oxford-swig-talks-twinkle-sparql-query-forms/) is worth looking at.